# C# Get Month Name to compare it

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I have a scenario, my database update table with one record every few minutes with a specific date. now I need to extract the month to check if month name equal to (April to October).

How to achieve that.

Please assist.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why check the *name* rather than whether the month is between 4 and 10 inclusive? Are you doing this in SQL? If so, where does the C# part come in? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, how to check month is between 4 and 10 in C#?

Comment: What about 4 and 10 should I redefine it as new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the month name as below:

```
  var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
  int month = dateTime.Month;
  if (month >= 4 && month <= 10)
  {
    // Month is between 4 & 10...
    // Get the full month name: dateTime.ToString("MMMM")
  }
```

Comment: Ok after I get the month name how to check it if it is between 4 to 10

Comment: For that, you need to get the month as a number. I have updated answer